# Elementary Os: Change firefox default icon

Tags: release-loki, elementary-website

All my icons are nice-looking, thanks to the elementary os theme. however, firefox icon is the default icon and not changed.
 I have installed ElementaryPlus theme to add additional icons but firefox was not included.
Anyone have tried changing firefox icon? is there a way to change it?

OS: Elementery OS Loki 0.4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the default `firefox.desktop` file:

First open terminal and copy the original one:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
```

Now edit the copy `~/.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop` with your favorite editor.

You need to adjust the line containing

```
Icon=firefox
```

to

```
Icon=/PATH/TO/YOUR/ICON
```

Mostly icons are stored under `/usr/share/icons/...` Probably you will find your desired icon there.

Comment: I also found a theme called Elementary-Add on Github which has a firefox elementary-styled icon. I copied the 48px sized icon and added it to ElementaryPlus theme folder. Then, turn off and on ElementaryConfigurator+ ... and it worked..!

Answer (score 0):

I found a theme called **Elementary-Add** theme which has a lot of Elementary-Styled icons including firefox.
I copied **firefox 48px icon**  from that theme and added it to Elementary Plus theme folder which I've already installed.

*ElemetaryPlus folder:*

```
/usr/share/icons/elementaryPlus/Apps/48
```

Then turned *Elementary+ Configurator* on and off. Icon changed!